# How to solve the following : Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/jndi/JndiException

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to upgrade a struts programme with hibernate 4.12 to Hibernate 5.0.0 and I'm also a beginner with Hibernate and currently learning it.

I can't see where is the class : org/hibernate/service/jndi/JndiException and understand what is the use of it, see error message below.

As I have updated the Hibernate version I had to rewrite the HibernateUtil class this way :

```
    public class HibernateUtil
{

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HibernateUtil.class);

    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory()
    {
        try
        {
            if (sessionFactory == null)
            {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure(HibernateUtil.class.getResource("/hibernate.cfg.xml"));
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
            serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();
            sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);            
            }

            logger.error("Juste avant buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry)");

            return sessionFactory;
        } catch (Throwable ex)
        {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown()
    {
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

I have this just after the login :

```
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/jndi/JndiException
10:12:29,673 ERROR ExceptionMappingInterceptor:38 - null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:446)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:285)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    at com.via.qcm.interceptor.CachingHeadersInterceptor.intercept(CachingHeadersInterceptor.java:35)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.via.qcm.interceptor.RolesInterceptor.intercept(RolesInterceptor.java:36)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:238)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:242)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:544)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2508)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2497)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.via.qcm.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:45)
    at com.via.qcm.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:17)
    at com.via.qcm.controller.QcmUserManager.getUser(QcmUserManager.java:29)
    at com.via.qcm.view.LoginAction.execute(LoginAction.java:26)
    ... 75 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/jndi/JndiException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2248)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2214)
    at org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory.<clinit>(AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.cache.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator.initiateService(RegionFactoryInitiator.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl$MetadataBuildingOptionsImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:663)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.<init>(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.getMetadataBuilder(MetadataSources.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:655)
    at com.via.qcm.util.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:29)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
    ... 98 more
```

My pom is actually so and I aim to have something like this at the end :

hibernate-core 5.2.2.Final, hibernate-c3p0 5.2.2.Final, 
hibernate-ehcach 5.2.2.Final, hibernate-envers  5.2.2.Final

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.via.qcm</groupId>
  <artifactId>CSM-CheckSkriptMonitor</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>CSM-CheckSkriptMonitor</name>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype.oss.snapshots</id>
        <name>Sonatype OSS Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>        
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>resources</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
            <directory>resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>versionApp</mainClass>
            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>
              true
            </addDefaultImplementationEntries>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.8</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
        <artifactId>displaytag</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>

        <exclusions>


            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>jcl104-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            </exclusion> 
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jsp-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> 
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>  
        <version>1.7.21</version>   
    </dependency>

    <!--  -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.21.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.21.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-tiles-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--  -->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.bootstrap</groupId>
       <artifactId>struts2-bootstrap-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
       <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
       <version>1.3.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!--
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.16</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-jquery-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
    </dependency>  

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-dojo-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.24.3</version>
    </dependency>
   -->   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.24.3</version>
    </dependency>





    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
          <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
          <version>1.10</version>
     </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <csm_version>csm 0.0.0</csm_version>
  </properties>
</project>
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: try to include hibernate-entitymanager in your pom.xml. It has to be the same version of hibernate-core(5.2.2?).

Comment: I did and that makes any differences, I have never used this library and don't see what it can change, but thanks for answering.